# Use of undefined constant APPATH - assumed 'APPATH'

Tags: codeigniter-3

I encounter this Error and i can't Fix it, Someone please help me T_T

---

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant APPATH - assumed 'APPATH'

Filename: controllers/Pages.php

Line Number: 4

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\controllers\Pages.php
Line: 4
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\index.php
Line: 315

### Function: require_once

and this is my Code

---

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller{
    public function view($page = 'home'){
        if(!file_exists(APPATH.'views/pages'.$page.'php')){
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

        $this->load->view('tenplates/Header');
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('tenplates/Footer');
    }

}
```

Comment: You are missing a P - it is APPPATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a message like...

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Use of undefined constant APPATH - assumed 'APPATH'
Filename: controllers/Pages.php
....
```

It means the constant, in this case APPATH is not defined. So could be a typo?

If you check out the user guide it states that it is actually APPPATH. A good way to remember it is imagining it as **APP**lication **PATH**.

3 "P"'s - not two.

So your code would then become...

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller{
    public function view($page = 'home'){
        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages'.$page.'php')){
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

        $this->load->view('tenplates/Header');
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('tenplates/Footer');
    }
}
```